# Solving typescript issue where I want a parameter to be one of the values of another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm using React and a store library with Typescript. Here I have an application type:

```
type ApplicationState = {
  loading: boolean;
  data: string[];
  colors: number[];
  alerts: Alerts;
  error: string;
}
```

Here I have a "setter" what can change the values for each key in the state individually:

```
const mySetter = (key: keyof ApplicationState, value: Partial<ApplicationState>) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [key]: value,
  }
}
```

Of course, the above throws a type error for the value parameter. The key is simple, I want the keys to be a key of the ApplicationState type. How can I tell typescript that I want the value to be one of the types of ApplicationState (instead of a union type)? I tried Partial and Pick, but typescript still throws errors at me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the use of generics and indexed access types, this constraint can be enforced in the type signature of `mySetter` as below:

```
<K extends keyof ApplicationState>(key: K, value: ApplicationState[K]) => ApplicationState
```

- Here we add a generic `K`, constrained to the keys of ApplicationState.
- `key` is simply of type `K`. Read more on generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html
- `value` looks up the type of key `K` in
  `ApplicationState` via an *indexed access type*. Read more here:
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Full code below, demonstrating the behaviour you're after:

```
type ApplicationState = {
  loading: boolean;
  data: string[];
  colors: number[];
  alerts: any;
  error: string;
}

const state: ApplicationState = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  colors: [],
  alerts: {},
  error: "some error"
}

const mySetter: <K extends keyof ApplicationState>(key: K, value: ApplicationState[K]) => ApplicationState = (key, value) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    [key]: value,
  }
}

// The following are happy, value is typed to whatever the type of the key is in ApplicationState type
mySetter("loading", false)
mySetter("data", [])
mySetter("colors", [1, 2])

// The following are unhappy, and will not compile, as desired.
mySetter("loading", "not-a-boolean-value")
mySetter("data", "not-an-array-of-strings")
mySetter("colors", { some: "object" })
```